# comparison of “if” statements use against direct use of logical operators

Tags: complexity-theory

To start with, I'll show some code:

```
//Declarations
bool cmp=filter();

//case 1
cmp && mainOperation();
cmp || elseOperation();

//case 2 :void*
cmp ?
   mainOperatiom() && 
   elseOperation() ;

//case 3
cmp || goto other;
mainOperation();
goto end;
other:
elseOperation();
end:

//case 0
if(cmp){
   mainOperation();
} else {
   elseOperation();
}
```

I'm actually not sure what the differences are between these codes from complexity view.

I'd like to know which case compiles the same as case 0? I mean which set of instructions will compile the same bytecode as the if statement.

Comment: If you want to know which code compiles to what, you need to specify a language, a compiler, and a platform before the question can be answered.  Alternatively, you could just examine the output from that compiler yourself!

Comment: thanks i've just realised it depends of compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Use case 0. It's readable, it's what any serious developer would use, it's the code that you are not asked to change in a code review, it's the code that I can read without thinking "what kind of xxxxx wrote this".

If you are even *thinking* about using another version to make your code run faster, then you need to learn how to save microseconds or milliseconds, not nanoseconds.

Comment: though I'm interested about complexity, i know that case 0 is more redable, still, i'm more interested about complexity, and what is the diference between those codes.